# Java Garbage Collection in HTTP Server (Spring Boot/Spring Web)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, garbage-collection, jvm

I know that in Java, memory is managed by the JVM and garbage collection will "free-up" de-referenced Objects that not longer have any reference pointing to them at all during the runtime of the application, i.e.

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(1);

myList = null;

// Potentially myList is elgible for garbage collection
```

My question is I have a Spring Boot application using Spring Web which has the embedded Tomcat server and its handling HTTP request from clients. How does Garbage collection work in these cases? The server will be running 24/7, but a client will make an HTTP request and data will be fetched from Database then returned to Controller, where the client will get some JSON back as HTTP response.

Will the JVM clear this Object holding data from the database or any Objects after the HTTP request is served? (This are not-Spring managed Objects, they are all instantiated in my codebase with "new" keyword) Or does it stay in JVM memory until garbage collection sees fit to remove it? I'm just trying to better understand the lifecycle of these objects here, as I am building ArrayLists of datafrom the database and returning it back to the Controller and I did not know if I need to manually call System.gc() or if I need to manually de-reference these Objects OR if they "die" after the HTTP request is complete for that unique client request.
[image]

Comment: Once object instances are dereferenced they are automatically removed by GC from memory when needed. You don't have to care about it. Even if you are eg. loading data from DB and then returning DB entities on endpoint it's not a problem. Spring will just convert them to response and throw them away. Once Controller execution is done, Spring will also close opened transaction (if is still opened) and will flush entity manager (if you are using Hibernate).

Answer (score 0):

> How does Garbage collection work in these cases?

The same way as in any other Java program.  Objects that are no reachable are deleted by the GC.

Unless you have done something really weird (and wrong), your application doesn't keep references to the objects that were created in request and response processing.

Likewise, the data that was written to the database will be in the database, and the temporary objects that were used to represent that data in Java memory will no longer be reachable.  Next time a request refers to that data, it will be read from the database and new temporary objects will be created to hold them for the duration of the request / response.

Note the database in not >in< the JVM.  The data is on a disk.  And typically the database service is a separate program running (often) on a different computer.  The GC has nothing to do with managing that data.

Neither the Spring Web framework or the persistence framework will *deliberately* keep references to the objects.  However, if your application *does* do something to make the above objects reachable in the long term, then it has a memory leak.  Eventually it fill up the heap with objects that can't be garbage collected and crash.  That is a bug ... in your application.